# How to load images one by one using css animations?

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I am working on solution in which basically i am creating simple banner where i want add some animations while loading animations.

So basically what i am trying to achieve is:

- there are 3 images which will load one after another once loading of three images is completed. i want to hide that images and display some random text for some seconds. this complete animation should perform infinitely.

I have written code but right now it is not working perfectly.

Here is code

```
<style>

div.img_320x50  {
  float: left;
  display: block;
-webkit-animation: fadein 2.5s infinite;
-moz-animation: fadein 2.5s infinite;
-o-animation: fadein 2.5s infinite;
animation: fadein 2.5s infinite;
  }
div.img_320x50:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 1s;
  opacity:1;
}
div.img_320x50:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: 1.5s;
  opacity:1;
}
div.img_320x50:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: 2s;
  opacity:1;
}

@keyframes fadein {
    0% {
        display: none;
        opacity: 0;
    }

    1% {
        display: block;
        opacity: 0;
    }

    99% {
        display: block;
        opacity: 1;
    }

    100% {
        display: none;
        opacity: 0;
    }
}



</style>
<div style="width:320px; height:250px; margin:0; padding:0; background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(8, 8, 10) 0%, rgb(38, 39, 44) 40%, rgb(38, 39, 44) 100%);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgb(8, 8, 10) 0%, rgb(38, 39, 44) 40%, rgb(38, 39, 44) 100%);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgb(8, 8, 10) 0%, rgb(38, 39, 44) 40%, rgb(38, 39, 44) 100%);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgb(8, 8, 10) 0%, rgb(38, 39, 44) 40%, rgb(38, 39, 44) 100%);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgb(8, 8, 10) 0%, rgb(38, 39, 44) 40%, rgb(38, 39, 44) 100%);
float:left;" >
    <div class="logo" style="margin-top:13px; width:320px; height:36px; text-align:center;float:left;">
        <img src="logo.jpg"/>
    </div>

    <div class="image-section" style="margin-top:13px; width:320px; margin-top:40px; clear:left; float:left;">
        <div class="320_50_image1 img_320x50 " style="float:left; left:10px; float:left; margin-left:30px;">
            <img src="image1.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="320_50_image2 img_320x50 " style="float:left; left:10px; float:left; margin-left:24px;">
            <img src="image2.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div class="320_50_image3 img_320x50 " style="float:left; left:10px; float:left; margin-left:24px;">
            <img src="image3.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="install_btn" style="margin-top:15px; width:320px; height:27px; text-align:center;float:left;">
        <button style="width:80px;height:35px;background:#689f38;border-radius:5px;color:#fff;border-color: #689f38;font-size: 14px;font-weight: 200;font-family: verdana; border-style:solid;">
            Install
        </button>
    </div>

</div>
```

Here is jsfiddle link for same : https://jsfiddle.net/c0Lmk43u/

Comment: What you want might be [how to add a delay between iterations](https://css-tricks.com/css-keyframe-animation-delay-iterations/) of the images so that you could display text between them.

Comment: What does *"not perfectly"* mean?

Comment: i want to load images one by one right now it appears first and than starts animation additional after one iteration of animation i want to hide that images and want to display text for few second after completion of text animation, images should appear again and this iterative animation of text and images should continue infinitely